# How to calculate whether a point lies inside a triangular prism

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm trying to figure out whether or not the current method I am using is correct.  I am trying to figure out whether a point lies inside of a triangular prism like the following:
[Geometry set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoojY.png)

None of the edges of this shape are necessarily parallel.  I am currently using the the points to create vectors p1, p2 and p3, and then using vector cross products to calculate the surface normals of each rectangular plane.  Then I calculate a vector from s to the midpoints of each of the upper triangles.  I take a dot product of this vector with the surface normal for each surface. One of these dot products looks like the following in case that was confusing: [Vector Geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g194.png)

If all three dot products are positive, or all three or negative, then the point lies within the plane (I do not necessarily know if the surface normal points in or out due to the way these objects are being tracked).  I would like to know if this is correct, or if there is a better way of calculating it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any convex volume, a point is inside if it has the same sign as the center (or any known interior point) when the coordinates are plugged in the equation of the planes of the faces.

Comment: Thank you.  So just to clarify, do you mean each face is checked individually, and all three must satisfy this condition?  ie I would test the known interior point with one face and check to make sure this sign is the same as the point being tested.  Then if both points have the same sign in all three faces then the point is inside?

Comment: @Stephen in all five faces.

Comment: Some more detail on the equation of the planes of faces would be very useful here. In addition, a diagram would also really help to improve this answer.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: the question should be moved to Mathematics.